# Echoing Array in an A-Z List

Tags: php, arrays, loops, alphabetical

Say I have the following array:

```
$aTest = array('apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'strawberry');
```

I need to be able to create a list from A-Z and show the relevant values from the array under each letter. E.g A - Apple, B - Banana, C - empty, D - empty, ... K - Kiwi .. P - Pear, Pineapple etc.

Can someone please help me? I assume I loop from A-Z using range but then im not sure how to echo out the relevant value from the array(and also in alphabetical order within each letter i.e pear before pineapple)

Thanks

Comment: How about sorting the array first? Then you just after to iterate over it and take the first letter as "index". Or you could even add `a` to `z` to the array, depending on how the output should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the use of conditionals and some built-in functions; this code is a little rough, but it does the trick:

```
<?php
    $aTest=array('apple','pear','banana','kiwi','pineapple','strawberry');
    $len=(count($aTest)-1);
    $letters=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
    $str=null;
    foreach($letters as $letter) {
        for($i=0;$i<=$len;$i++) {
            $str=strtoupper($letter).' - ';
            if(strtolower(substr($aTest[$i],0,1))==strtolower($letter)) {
                $str.=$aTest[$i];
                break;
            } elseif($i==$len) {
                $str.='empty';
            }
        }
        echo($str.'<br />');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I amended this slightly so used $letters = range('a','z'); but apart from that it seems to do the trick. The other answers didn't echo out the letters that were not in the array e.g b,c,d,e etc but I need them also, they just need to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use `sort()` to get them all in order. Then, track the first letter. Anytime it changes, save and output it.

```
sort( $aTest );

$currChar = '';
foreach ( $aTest as $word) {
  if ( $word[0] != $currChar ) {
    $currChar = $word[0];
    echo $currChar . PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo $word . PHP_EOL;
}
```

From your initial array, this would produce the following:

```
a
apple
b
banana
k
kiwi
p
pear
pineapple
s
strawberry
```

Comment: Great point, @Kaii. There are a couple other ways to shorten it too, which I'm playing with and may provide in the answer - though readability is going out the window.

Comment: @Kaii Here you go: `sort($a);foreach($a as $w)echo($w[0]!=$l)&&($l=$w[0])?$l.$w:$w;` :)

Comment: FTFY ;) `$l=0;sort($a);foreach($a as $w)echo($w[0]!=$l)&&($l=$w[0])?$l.$w:$w;`

Comment: even if PHPs allows the use of unintialized variables (and throws *only* a notice when doing so), you should initialize them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$aTest = array('apple', 'pineapple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'pear', 'strawberry');

$range = range('a','z');

$output = array();

foreach($range AS $letters){
    foreach($aTest AS $fruit){
        if(strtolower($fruit[0]) == $letters){
            $output[$letters][] = $fruit;
        }
    }
}

foreach($output AS $letter => $fruits){
    echo $letter . "<br/>--------<br/>\n";
    sort($fruits);
    foreach($fruits AS $indFruit){
        echo $indFruit . "<br/>\n";
    }
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```